# Integracion HTML5 y SQL Server

Tags: php, sql-server

Algun curso o taller o lo que sea.. jeje. Que me puedan recomendar para la integracion de HTML5 con SQL Server. Hablemos que por convencon MySQL es mas amigable y/o flexible enlazarlo tanto a HTML5 , pero si ustedes pudieran orientarme para introducirme  y entender este grupo de tecnologias en conjunto, les estaria muy agradecida.

Antes de preguntarme porque no utilize MS por VS, ASP o algo asi, sera por obvias razones de apuntar a plataformas alternas que se desplazen en codigo libre sin tantas limitaciones... y solo por gusto. (y odio comun hacia Microsoft.)
Espero no incomodar u ofender a nadie con mi pregunta.

Muchas gracias a todos y Saludos:)

Comment: como comenta @Adriana Hernández , HTML5 no es un lenguaje de programación, no hay manera que conectes HTML5 con una base de datos sin utilizar un lenguaje de lado del servidor. PD: la etiqueta _php_ esta **fuera de lugar, ¿no?**

Comment: No le pongan -1, pero @Zoroya Ramos, debemos de tener un poquito de criterio a la hora de preguntar cosas asi.

Comment: Wow, me doy cuenta de lo tolerantes que son a un nueva persona interesada en adquirir nuevos conocimientos.. son ustedes muy amables y considerados..! Si bien, HTML5(hacia referencia al frontend html-css-js) pero LES PIDO UNA ETERNA DISCULPA, tienen razon la intgracion correcta debe de ser desde el backend, en este caso la etiqueta PHP hacia referencia a eso mismo. Integracion PHP-SQL Server. Gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como ya te lo mencionaron, `HTML` **no** es un lenguaje de programación sino un **lenguaje de marcado**, simplemente el esqueleto de un documento. Por ejemplo, los archivos de Office (Word, Excel, PowerPoint, etc.) son ahora [archivos descritos en `XML`](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_Open_XML), un lenguaje de marcado tal y como el HTML pero con [otras características](http://www.internetmania.net/int0/int59.htm).
Un navegador web simplemente interpreta ese `HTML` junto con el [`CSS`](http://www.maestrosdelweb.com/introcss/) para representarlo de forma gráfica.

En lo que se refiere a los *"lenguajes del lado del servidor"* es una parte de **programación como tal** en un entorno web (pero no la única). El servidor procesa peticiones y, gracias a estos lenguajes, **es capaz de generar automáticamente documentos HTML** que contengan la información necesaria. El lenguaje *libre* más popular para ello es `PHP`.

Finalmente, para aplicar programación del lado del cliente se necesita de otro lenguaje de programación (el HTML no, vamos) que generalmente es [JavaScript](https://www.javascript.com/learn/javascript/objects) (aunque hay algunas [otras opciones](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13156809/5360283)).

Te dejo una excelente compilación de [lenguajes de desarrollo web](http://www.maestrosdelweb.com/los-diferentes-lenguajes-de-programacion-para-la-web/) para que te quede algo más claro.

Comment: A eso mismo me referia, tu lo has dicho _"En lo que se refiere a los "lenguajes del lado del servidor" es una parte de programación como tal en un entorno web **(pero no la única)."**_  Partiendo de este punto creo que llevo mas tiempo trabajando del lado diseño que el del server, asi que por inercia adopto la integracion HTML5 como una extension de PHP y/o MySQL, bueno de echo asi aprendi frontend y fue por eso que formule la pregunta de esta manera, pero ahora que se aclaro, voy iniciar una integracion PHP-SQL Server, he encontrado mas MySQL y muy poco o casi nada de SQL-Server. Saludos!

Comment: @ZorayaRamos MySQL es gratuito, SQL Server lo es también pero en su versión Developer y en Express. Yo trabajo con ese servidor y aunque hay muchas diferencias en comandos, aprendes que es solo en la forma, no en el fondo. Saludos igualmente!

Comment: Bueno, lo se. MySQL es de lo mejor! Pero por desgracia donde me encuentro actualmente impera el SQL Server como standard y bajo licencia coporativa, asi que por lo pronto no me queda otra que adaptarme a esta misma tecnologia:)

Comment: Aprovéchalo, sé que existe aversión a la marca Microsoft pero verás que de hecho es bastante potente, y más si tienes versiones 2012 para arriba :D te lo digo con la experiencia de estarlo usando por más de año y medio. Otra cosa, también vale la pena que pruebes con `C#` hacer un proyecto **MVC** en Visual Studio ;)

Comment: Jejeje, gracias por el consejo, pero la verdad mi intencion es migrar a otra plataforma a largo plazo y desvancar MS. Creo que la aversion es muy fuerte y mi vision es buscar una combinacion stack open equiparable o superior a el stack VisualStudio o .net por excelencia.

Answer (score 12):

Simplemente no se puede integrar `HTML5` con ninguna base de datos.

Tienes errores de conceptos en tu pregunta. `HTML` es un lenguaje simple que solamente define una estructura básica en un documento web, o sea con él puedes trabajar con los componentes visuales de una página, ya sea texto, imágenes videos, etc... y por ser un lenguaje que se ejecuta del lado del cliente (o sea en el navegador web) no tiene la capacidad para conectarse con ninguna base de datos.

Esa tarea solamente le corresponde a lenguajes que se ejecuten del lado del servidor como `PHP`, `Python`, etc, con los que puedes manejar conexiones con bases de datos y todos los demás procesos lógicos que requiera tu sitio, como por ejemplo la gestión de información de dicha base de datos.

Por tanto, si quieres hacer un sitio utilizando bases de datos de `SQL Server`, lo primero que tienes que hacer es elegir un lenguaje del lado del servidor y luego investigar como conectarte a tu BD con dicho lenguaje.

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo con @Adriana Hernández, por otro lado si quieres utilizar SQL Server como motor de base de datos hay conectores para PHP, debes primero definir en que lenguaje del lado del servidor quieres trabajar para orientarte.

Comment: Totalmente de acuerdo Julio, es PHP desde donde pienso partir, la verdad he buscado mucho material de integracion DB con PHP, pero lo que mas abunda en la red es con MySQL, lamentablemente el standard que existe donde me encuentro es por lincencia coporativa de SQL Server... asi que, pues vamos trabajar con lo que tenemos. Y con algun resultado de esto, proponer una alternativa a larga plazo con MySQL. Saludos!

Comment: Te dejo una liga donde se encuentra un ejemplo básico para conectar PHP con SQL Server, espero te sirva.
[ http://php.net/manual/es/function.sqlsrv-connect.php ]

Comment: la respuesta que diste para el usuario es correcta sin embargo hay bases de datos del lado del cliente llamadas [WebSQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_SQL_Database) , simplemente con darle f12 al navegador seleccionas storage podras visualizar la base de datos(solo en valido navegadores limitados!!)